# Font adds a shade to the letter "W" when made it bold

Tags: css, fonts

I am using "FivoSans" font in my website and spotted a strange behaviour of the font when the added some font-weight to the font.

The font "FivoSans" is a font that I received from the client. And I added the font to the site using below code.

```
/* Fontface Imports */
@font-face {
    font-family: "FivoSans";
    src: url(/content/theme/fonts/FivoSans/FivoSans- Regular.otf) format("opentype");
}
```

The letter "W" has a little shade (or does not gets the font-weight added properly) when font-weight goes above 400.

[image]

Notice the letter "W" in News.

Following is the capture of inspect element in Google Chrome.
[image]

Is there a way to fix this and does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you share a link demonstrating this? Have you right-clicked and done "inspect element" to see if there's anything in there?

Comment: hmm..demo can be hard as i am under an NDA with the client unfortunately. But yes, I did inspect the element. I updated to add an screenshot of the inspect element to the question.

Comment: where does the "FivoSans" come from? How do you add it to your CSS / HTML?

Comment: @Raptor I added the code I used to add the font to the question. There are other versions of font files for this font. (I added Regular font, there are Thin, Medium, Bold, Thicker, etc. font files but I didn't add them.)

Comment: Actually you can make a minimal example in snippet or JSFiddle